# tkinter return names of dynamic checkboxes

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I'm trying to write my first script in python & tkinter.

I blocked and I'm lost when I need to get in variable the name of each checkboxes selected when I click on the button <kbd>Validate</kbd>.

Checkboxes are dynamic from text files. Sample file:

```
item1
item2
...
item100
```

A screen of the GUI:

[image: screenshot showing checkbuttons and validate button]

Here's my code:
(In `#` code is what I tried without success.)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Label, Entry
import glob

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.master.title("My Menu")

        menubar = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)

        submenu = Menu(fileMenu)
        submenu.add_command(label="lst1", command=self.onDisplay)
        submenu.add_command(label="lst2")
        submenu.add_command(label="lst3")
        fileMenu.add_cascade(label='Listing', menu=submenu, underline=0)

        fileMenu.add_separator()

        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=0, command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)

    ## Here the function which display checkboxes
    def onDisplay(self):
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        frame1 = Frame(self)
        frame1.pack(fill=BOTH)
        lbl1 = Label(frame1, text="Choice", width=6)
        path = '/root/liste/*.txt'
        files=glob.glob(path)
        count = 0
        #var = dict()
        for file in files:
            with open(file, 'r') as lst_file:
                for item in lst_file:
                    #var[item]=IntVar()
                    #cb = Checkbutton(frame1, text=item.rstrip(), variable=var[item], command=self.cb)
                    ##Here all checkboxes generated dynamically
                    cb = Checkbutton(frame1, text=item.rstrip())
                    cb.grid(row=count//10, column=count%10)
                    #cb.pack()
                    count += 1
        #btn1 = Button(self, text='Validate', font=("Arial", 12), command=self.cb)
        btn1 = Button(self, text='Validate', font=("Arial", 12))
        btn1.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)

    def cb(self):
        print("variable is", self.var.get())

    def onExit(self):

        self.quit()

def main():

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("800x550+300+300")
    app = Example()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't figure out everything your code is trying to do with respect to handling multiple files, but the following shows a cleaned-up and functioning version of it showing a way to keep track which `Checkbutton`s have been selected by the user.

Most of the important changes were to the `onDisplay()` method—although I also changed the name of the `def cb(self):` method you had to `def validate(self):` to match the `Button` name (because I found calling it `cb` confusing since that's also the name of a local variable in `onDisplay()`).

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Label, Entry
import glob

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.master.title("My Menu")

        menubar = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menubar)

        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)

        submenu = Menu(fileMenu)
        submenu.add_command(label="lst1", command=self.onDisplay)
        submenu.add_command(label="lst2")
        submenu.add_command(label="lst3")
        fileMenu.add_cascade(label='Listing', menu=submenu, underline=0)

        fileMenu.add_separator()

        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=0, command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)

    ## Here is the function which displays checkboxes
    def onDisplay(self):
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        frame1 = Frame(self)
        frame1.pack(fill=BOTH)
        lbl1 = Label(frame1, text="Choice", width=6)
#        path = '/root/liste/*.txt'
        path = './root_liste1.txt'  # changed for my testing.
        files=glob.glob(path)

        self.var = dict()
        count = 0
        for file in files:
            with open(file, 'r') as lst_file:
                for item in lst_file:
                    item = item.rstrip()
                    status = BooleanVar()
                    self.var[item] = status
                    cb = Checkbutton(frame1, text=item, variable=status)
                    cb.grid(row=count//10, column=count%10)
                    count += 1

        btn1 = Button(self, text='Validate', font=("Arial", 12),
                      command=self.validate)
        btn1.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5)

    def validate(self):  # btn1 callback
        print('checked items:')
        for item, status in self.var.items():
            if status.get():  # Checked?
                print('  ', item)

    def onExit(self):
        self.quit()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("800x550+300+300")
    app = Example()
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Many thanks Martineau,for explanations. It's exactly what i searched